# How to change polymer element style

Tags: html, css, polymer

Created a custom polymer element "autocomplete" which include existing polymer element "paper-autocomplete"."paper- autocomplete" element class has "paper-input" element with specific style. How can I change "paper-input" element style in "autocomplete" element class(which calls "paper-autocomplete")?

Comment: Avoiding deprecated CSS declarations...it depends how the inner component exposes styling.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti sorry my question was incorrectly displayed, here is full question

Answer (score 1):

The `paper-input` element uses the `paper-input-container`, so you can define a set of [CSS variables](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties) to style it, in the intended/allowed way.

If you check the source for `paper-input-container` [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input-container.js), and look under "### Styling" you will see all the options you have to style the element from "outside".

Answer (score 0):

In the paper-autocomplete element add the following:

```
  paper-input {
    @apply --my-styles;
  }
```

In the parent element where you incorporate paper-autocomplete add:

```
paper-autocomplete {
  --my-styles: {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  };
}
```

Comment: How would that work? Are you suggesting to edit a 3rd party component created by a team at Google?

Comment: can you send a link of the component you are using?

Comment: she said it's `paper-input`, so https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input

Comment: @d.mares  sure, no i am using paper-autocomplete which include paper-input inside . and i want to change paper input through paper-autocomplete. if you will check the link please check account-autocomplete i did something like this. Thanks (https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete)

Comment: there is no ccs mixim for the paper-input, you can not style it, you would have to recreate the element and make it yours, then apply a mixim to the paper input